# convert array with objects to one associative array without foreach

Tags: php

I have an array like(result of json_decode):

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(6) "sample"
    ["startYear"]=>
    string(4) "2000"
    ["endYear"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(13) "second_sample"
    ["startYear"]=>
    string(4) "1986"
    ["endYear"]=>
    string(4) "1991"
  }
}
```

I want to convert it to array like:

```
 array(2) {
  ["sample"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["startYear"]=>
    string(4) "2000"
    ["endYear"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
  }
  ["second_sample"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["startYear"]=>
    string(4) "1986"
    ["endYear"]=>
    string(4) "1991"
  }
}
```

Is there beauty way to do this (cureently I'm using foreach, but I'm not sure it is a best solution).

Added a code example:

```
<?php
$str='[{"key":"sample","startYear":"2000","endYear":"2015"},{"key":"second_sample","startYear":"1986","endYear":"1991"}]';

$arr=json_decode($str);

var_dump($arr);

$newArr=array();

foreach ($arr as $value){
$value=(array)$value;
$newArr[array_shift($value)]=$value;

}

var_dump($newArr);
```

Comment: Using `foreach` sounds like a pretty sane approach to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-reduce.php)

```
$myArray = array_reduce($initialArray, function ($result, $item) {
    $item = (array) $item;

    $key = $item['key'];
    unset($item['key']);

    $result[$key] = $item;

    return $result;
}, array());
```

Comment: I'd explicitly get the key `key` instead of relying on the order with `array_shift`; JSON dictionaries have no intrinsic order.

Comment: You're right @deceze .. I will update my answer.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create the desired output without making any iterated function calls by using a technique called "array destructuring" (which is a functionless version of `list()`).  [Demo](https://3v4l.org/0Xtli)

Language Construct Style:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $object) {
    [
        'key' => $key,
        'startYear' => $result[$key]['startYear'],
        'endYear' => $result[$key]['endYear']
    ] = (array)$object;
}
var_export($result);
```

Functional Style:

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $array,
        function($result, $object) {
            [
                'key' => $key,
                'startYear' => $result[$key]['startYear'],
                'endYear' => $result[$key]['endYear']
            ] = (array)$object;
            return $result;
        },
        []
    )
);
```

Both will output:

```
array (
  'sample' => 
  array (
    'startYear' => '2000',
    'endYear' => '2015',
  ),
  'second_sample' => 
  array (
    'startYear' => '1985',
    'endYear' => '1991',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use `array_map` like as

```
$result = array_map('get_object_vars',$your_array);
```

**Edited:**

As after checking your code that you've added an example over here there's no need to use an extra functions or loop to convert your array of objects into associative array instead you simply need to pass second parameter `true` within `json_decode` function like as

```
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/471510)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10248821)

Comment: @RajeshJadav How does this not provide an answer?

Comment: I think this answer should be comment

Comment: First of all you're an android developer and user has requested for the answer that doesn't required `foreach` and did you tried this answer even once. @RajeshJadav

Comment: The answer provably does not provide the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to array_reduce and other provided solutions could be:

```php
$list = array_combine(
  array_column($list, 'key'),
  array_map(fn ($item) => (array) $item, array_values($list))
);
```

Or:

```php
$list = array_combine(
  array_column($list, 'key'),
  array_map('get_object_vars', $list)
);
```