# Convert Array to Associative Object

Tags: php, laravel

I want to convert:

INPUT:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => {#476 ▼
    "click": 2412
    "ctr": 121
    "id": 12
    "trueview": 4124
    "view": 1452503
  }
  1 => {#478 ▼
    "click": 2222
    "ctr": 2222
    "id": 21
    "trueview": 2222
    "view": 2222
  }
  2 => {#1526 ▼
    "click": 3333
    "ctr": 3333
    "id": 31
    "trueview": 3333
    "view": 3333
  }
]
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
  "12" : {
           "click": 2222,
           "trueview": 3333,
           "view": 3333,
           "ctr": 3333
         },
  "21" : {
           "click": 2222,
           "trueview": 3333,
           "view": 3333,
           "ctr": 3333
         },
  "31" : {
           "click": 2222,
           "trueview": 3333,
           "view": 3333,
           "ctr": 3333
         }
}
```

Comment: use `collect()` helper method and then encode in json format

Comment: you can typecast array to object `$object = (object) $array;`

Comment: Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781680/convert-array-with-objects-to-one-associative-array-without-foreach

Answer (score 0):

Loop the initial array and create a new array using the `id` as an index. In code:

```
$new_array = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $vals) {
    $id = $vals['id'];
    unset($vals['id']);
    $new_array[$id] = $vals;
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I fixed it : 

$new_array = [];

        foreach ($listLogAd as $key => $vals) {
            $id = $vals->id;
            unset($vals->id);
            $new_array[$id] = $vals;
        }
dd($new_array);

Answer (score 0):

Try this... you should get something... but you might need to make few changes depending upon your need

```
<?php
       

$arrays = array(
   0 =>  array(       
       "click" => 2412,
       "view" => 12456
       ),
   1=> array(
            "click"=> 2222,
            "ctr"=> 2222,
            "id"=> 21,
            "trueview"=> 2222,
            "view"=> 2222,
        )
);

echo "{\n";
foreach ($arrays as $index => $array)
{
    echo '"'.strval($index).'"'.":  {\n";
        
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        echo '"'.($key).'":'.$value.",\n";
    }
    echo "\n\t},\n";
  
}

  echo "\n }";
```